# If element: rather than if element not None won't work

Tags: python, if-statement

From what I understand this should just pass by the if statement if there is no email column present but it's throwing `KeyError: None` when it gets to the if statement. Could someone help me understand this rule? Thanks!

```
def not_isin(df1, df2, phone_col, df2phone_col,website_col, df2website_col,company_col, df2company_col, email_col, df2email_col):
    print("entered not_isin")
    df1 = df1[~df1[phone_col].isin(df2[df2phone_col])]
    df1 = df1[~df1[website_col].isin(df2[df2website_col])]
    df1 = df1[~df1[company_col].isin(df2[df2company_col])]
    if df1[email_col] and df2[df2email_col]:
        df1 = df1[~df1[email_col].isin(df2[df2email_col])]
        return df1
    return df1
```

Comment: What's the value of `email_col` and `df2email_col`?

Comment: And once you fix this, I think you'll run into the common error "The truth value of a series is ambiguous". Don't try to use a dataframe as a boolean.

Comment: @Barmar email col is 'email' and df2email_col is 'Email' in this case. I get the email cols like so because they come in different on each new dataset. def get_email(df):
    email = [col if col.lower().startswith('email') else None for col in df][0]
    return email 
Then I assign it like email_col = get_email(df1)

Comment: I'm just trying to find if the column name is present in the dataframe headers.

Comment: But if the column name isn't present, you get a `KeyError`. You have to check if the column exists before trying to use it as an index.

Comment: It should be `if email_col in df1 and df2email_col in df2:`

Comment: Oh I see the error in my understanding of it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I think it fails at `df1[email_col]`.

Obviously, if `email_col` is `None`, you get a `KeyError` before even reaching the `if` statement.

Comment: Thank you Jerome! I was under the impression that if df1[email_col] was the equivalent of " if the email column exists in this dataframe then proceed with the logic of the if statement. Am I mistaken?